# Laravel Custom Request not catching the unique in the rules when creating custom messages

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have read the docs like 12 times and I created the following:

```
class LSDLocationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'organization_id'  => 'required',
            'name'             => 'required|unique:lsd_locations'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.unique:lsd_locations' => 'The LSD name is already used by a LSD Location.',
        ];
    }
}
```

In the controller I do:

```
public function store(LSDLocationRequest $request, Organization $organization) {
    $request->validated();

    // ...
}
```

When I submit this form the first time with a name of Sample Location, it works. When I do it the second time with the same name, it shows me:

> The name has already been taken.

I am 110% sure this is the correct controller action it's coming into. Why is it not showing me my custom message? I have a unique key on the name field in the table. It's ignoring my `name.unique:lsd_locations` and writing the default message.

- The table exists.
- The column exists.
- There is a unique constraint for name on this table.

**Why is it not using my message? Why is it using the default message?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the message to:

```
name.unique
```

So it should be like this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'name.unique' => 'The LSD name is already used by a LSD Location.',
    ];
}
```